# PHP - Read array with spaces

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass, sub-array

I want to read these numbers (like 3,3,3,2,2,3) out of a stdClass Object.
But i don't know how to read arrays with spaces in it.

Could anybody help me? :/

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [2015-06-03 00:00:00] => 3
    [2015-06-03 00:15:00] => 3
    [2015-06-03 00:30:00] => 3
    [2015-06-03 00:45:00] => 2
    [2015-06-03 01:00:00] => 2
    [2015-06-03 01:15:00] => 3
    [2015-06-03 01:30:00] => 2
    [2015-06-03 01:45:00] => 2
    [2015-06-03 02:00:00] => 2
```

Comment: Have you tried something or did some research?

Comment: You'd be better off converting that stdObject into an array and use a foreach.

Comment: @Rizier123 - I did, but i didn't found anything helpful.

Comment: @Andrew - I wanna read only one of these. like every day at 00:00:00.

Comment: Again, you could convert it to a array and thus having access to all the juicy array_* functions available in php. You could then slice the key to get the desired output.